# Power BI Rest API - AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the XXXXX directory

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I'm trying to get an access token instead of getting this error message

```
AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the XXXXX directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.\r\nTrace ID: f18021a8-b10a-40bf-9f0a-7975b38e2300\r\nCorrelation ID: 4f61c8f5-ed06-41f1-8d7b-756dd7c09e10\r\nTimestamp: 2020-12-16 03:27:49Z","error_codes":[50034],"timestamp":"2020-12-16 03:27:49Z","trace_id":"f18021a8-b10a-40bf-9f0a-7975b38e2300","correlation_id":"4f61c8f5-ed06-41f1-8d7b-756dd7c09e10","error_uri":"https://login.windows.net/error?code=50034"}
```

My python code

```
import adal
import json
import pyodbc
import requests

AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.windows.net/XXXXX'
RESOURCE = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXX'
userid='nurdin@xxxxx.com.my'
userpassword='xxxxx'
completedtime = []
verify = []

def make_headers(access_token):
    return {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
    }

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL)
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(RESOURCE,userid,userpassword,CLIENT_ID)
access_token = token['accessToken']
print(access_token)
```

Comment: Is your account a personal account or work account?

Comment: @JoyWang work account

Comment: Is it under the tenant `XXXXX` in `https://login.windows.net/XXXXX`? Or it is in another tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my side, make sure your work account is under the tenant in the `AUTHORITY_URL`, if not, you could follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory#add-a-new-user) to create a new user without MFA-enabled.

```
import adal

AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.windows.net/<tenant-id>'
RESOURCE = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
CLIENT_ID = '<client-id>'
userid='username@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com'
userpassword='xxxxxx'

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL)
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(RESOURCE,userid,userpassword,CLIENT_ID)
access_token = token['accessToken']
print(access_token)
```

[image]